# creating a password protected zip file using child process in nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, child-process, fs

I have a very funny issue. I am spawning a child process in nodejs to create a zip password protected file. It is supposed to emulate the following command.

```
zip -P password -rf finalFileName.zip filePath
```

here is the code I wrote

```
function(password, zipName) {

            let zip = spawn('zip', ['-P rolemodel','-rj', zipName, this.folderPath ]);

            return this;

    }
```

On unzipping the final zip file, I get an invalid password error.

Anything wrong that I am doing here ? I am however able to execute the command on the terminal and get the whole thing to work.

Comment: Does the password `rolemodel-rj` work ? Besides that: one time you use `-rf` and the other time `-rj`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to put every argument in quotes like following:

```
zip = spawn('zip',['-P', 'password' , '-rj', 'archive.zip', 'complete path to archive file']);
zip .on('exit', function(code) {
...// Do something with zipfile archive.zip
...// which will be in same location as file/folder given
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked, I am using the synchronous method. I was passing the parameters wrong.